# copy data from 1Db to another using Dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, odbc, oledb

Sorry if my english is not so good, I will try to explain the problem.

I need to copy all data from a Table of a Acces mdb (connected with OleDB) to a Table of a MySql DB (connected with ODBC)

I made a working solution, but it's very slow, and so I want to try other solutions to check if they can give me more performance.

The solution connecting to the mdb, using a DataReader, then for each row in Datareader I make an INSERT into the Mysql Table ( before copy I truncate the table to get it empty)

The records are more than 10K and this operation is very slow, and do be onest I need to do the same thing on other 2 tables also very big as this one.

I cannot make a direct sql insert ( as `INSERT INTO A in ..... SELECT * FROM B`) because the 1 DB has a OleDB conn and the other has a ODBC conn.

So I thought to try to make this operation using `TableAdapters` and `DataSet`, but I'm not able to make it working.

The problem is that the Dataset's `HasChanges` is `false`

If you need some code I can post, but what I do is following:

- Connection to MDb
- Create OleDbTableAdapter
- Create DataSet
- Fill DataSet with TableAdapter
- Connection to MySqlDB
- Create ODBCTableAdapter
- Using Update command of ODBCTableAdapter with the first Dataset.

But DS has no changes commited so he don't write anything to DB, so I thought to use another Dataset and copy data from DS1 to DS2 to add rows, see if has.changes was true and the making Update command of ODBCTableadapter using DS2.

I tryed to copy data between datasets:

```
ds2 = ds1.copy
```

I tried also to use dataset import function, looping `DS1` datarows and Importing all rows from `DS1` to `DS2`.
In both cases the rows are added to DS2, but still `HasChanges` is false, what can I do?
Just to clarify possible questions I didn't use `DS.Acceptchanges`, PrimaryKey is defined, The `UpdateCommand` is defined, DS has data (I populate 2 DataGrids to check it).
No errors given, just no data written on DB.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advice.

Comment: You cannot use UpdateCommand of first TableAdapter for your MySqlConnection. You have to insert each DataRow from first DataTable into second(MySQL) DataTable. Then use the TableAdapter of your MySQL-Table to update this DataTable.

Comment: yes yes, Maybe I explained bad, it's what I did, I populated the second Datatable, but for vb, Datatable han no changes and so when i call update for the MysqlTableAdapter it doesn't write anything to DB.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can speed up the process in a great deal would be to batch your SQL update commands. Otherwise each update request will be executed one at a time.

You might want to consider the MySQL [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) command to facilitate the rapid import of large amounts of data.

I wasn't able to locate a function comparable to MS SQL Server's [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class, but if your MySQL library supports a similar function that may be of interest as well.

In general, the less network traffic you generate the faster you'll be able to perform large database inserts (although there can be other limiting factors after a point).

Comment: Ok, I will try to check that command. Before I did this operation with Access using linked tables and it was very fast, becouse I simply did it with a sql command (INSERT INTO tab2 SELECT * tab1)in vb.net it's more difficult. But I wanted to do it cuz the finally result I would like to obtain is to make a resident vb app on the server that catch when Access DB is modified and update MysqlDb immidiatly. But I think that will be more difficult

Comment: Eh, LOAD DATA INFILE seems to be what I'm searching for, but nothing comes simple as always eheheh now I have to check how to convert the mdb to a csv before using that command ''^^